# CDF of Inverse Gaussian Distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, derivatives

I want to find the derivative of CDF of inverse gaussian distribution w.r.t. to parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$. The PDF and CDF of inverse gaussian distribution is given as:

$$f(x; \lambda, \mu )= \sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{2\pi x^3}}e^{- \frac{\lambda(x-\mu^2)}{2\mu^2 x}}  ~  , \quad x>0, \lambda>0, \mu>0 \\
F(x|\lambda, \mu)= \Phi\Bigg[\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}(\frac{x}{\mu}-1)\Bigg]+ e^\frac{2\lambda}{\mu}\Phi\Bigg[-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}(1+\frac{x}{\mu})\Bigg] .$$

I would appreciate it if you would like to give me any help.

Thanks

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Use the [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and [chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) rules. I'll get you started with the derivative with respect to $\lambda$:
\begin{multline*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\left[\Phi\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}-1\right)\right)+\exp\left(2\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}+1\right)\right)\right]\\
=\Phi^{\prime}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}-1\right)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}-1\right)\right]+\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\left[\exp\left(2\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)\right]\Phi\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}+1\right)\right)\\
+\exp\left(2\frac{\lambda}{\mu}\right)\Phi^{\prime}\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}+1\right)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}\left[-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\mu}+1\right)\right]=\cdots
\end{multline*}
Note that $\Phi^\prime$ is the PDF of a [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Standard_normal_distribution).